# How do I setup a counter to count seconds using Verilog

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to make a second counter and millisecond counter using Verilog. The Problem is that whenever I run a simulation, the value of the second counter (`clk_1sec`) and millisecond counter (`clk_1msec`) is fixed to 0.

My Simulation shows proper result until 19th line of the code, but the simulation doesn't show the proper result of `clk_1sec` and `clk_1msec` (value of those two counters are fixed to 0)

```
module clk_gen(clk_5k, reset, loopcount, clk_1sec, clk_1msec);

input clk_5k, reset;
output [14:0] loopcount;
output clk_1sec, clk_1msec;
reg [14:0] loopcount;
reg clk_1sec, clk_1msec;

always @(posedge clk_5k or negedge reset)

begin

  if (~reset)
    begin
      clk_1sec <= 0; clk_1msec <= 0; loopcount <= 0;
    end

  else
    loopcount <= loopcount + 2'b10;
    begin
      if (loopcount += 13'b1001110001000)
        clk_1sec = ~clk_1sec;

      else if (loopcount += 3'b101)
        clk_1msec = ~clk_1msec;
      end
    end
  end
end
endmodule
```

Expected result is that `clk_1sec` should change its value when the value of `loopcount` is `loopcount + 5000` (decimal) and `clk_1msec` should change its value when the value of `loopcount` is `loopcount + 5` (decimal).

Comment: What do you think `if (loopcount += 3'b101)` will do?

Comment: I've just tried the code and following error occurred : Operator only allowed in systemVerilog

Answer (score 1):

There are some misunderstandings in your code:

- You are using blocking assignments inside clocked always. You should use only non blocking assignments.
- You are using 13 bit constants to operate with a 15 bit register (loopcount). You should use 15 bit constants.
- And above all, you are using an improper way to tell if the value of loopcount is multiple of 5 (to count miliseconds). Multiples of something that is not a power of two is difficult to implement in hardware. Either you should use a power of two clock signal (32.768 kHz is a common clock for these applications) or you should use a counter to count cycles to get miliseconds and another one to count miliseconds to get one second.

Assuming a 32.768 kHz clock, your module would go like this:

```
module clk_gen (
  input wire clk32768,
  input wire reset,
  output reg [15:0] loopcount,
  output wire clk_1sec,
  output wire clk_1msec
  );

  assign clk_1sec  = loopcount[15];  // 1 exact second (32768 counts)
  assign clk_1msec = loopcount[5];   // not quite 1ms, but 0.97ms

  always @(posedge clk32768 or negedge reset) begin
    if (~reset)
      loopcount <= 16'd0;
    else
      loopcount <= loopcount + 16'd1;
  end
endmodule
```

If you need to stick with a 5KHz clock and/or need precise milisecond measurement (within the limits of your clock oscillator), then you can do as this:

```
module clk_gen (
  input wire clk_5k,
  input wire reset,
  output reg clk_1sec,
  output reg clk_1msec
  );

  reg [2:0] counter_cycles;  // counts from 0 to 4 cycles => 1ms
  reg [9:0] counter_msecs;   // counts from 0 to 999 msecons => 1s

  always @(posedge clk_5k or negedge reset) begin
    if (~reset) begin
      clk_1sec <= 1'b0;
      clk_1msec <= 1'b0;
      counter_cycles <= 3'd0;
      counter_msecs <= 10'd0;
    end
    else begin
      if (counter_cycles == 3'd4) begin
        counter_cycles <= 3'd0;
        clk_1msec <= ~clk_1msec;
        if (counter_msecs == 10'd999) begin
          counter_msecs <= 10'd0;
          clk_1sec <= ~clk_1sec;
        end
        else begin
          counter_msecs <= counter_msecs + 10'd1;
        end
      end
      else begin
        counter_cycles <= counter_cycles + 3'd1;
      end
    end
  end
endmodule
```

You can edit/simulate this version at 
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3CjH

Comment: Thanks a lot. The reason why I had to stick to 5khz clock is because that was the requirement of the code I've been working on. Now what's left for me is to understand the code you wrote and design a testbench for that. Again, thank you very much

Comment: The link I provided to EDA playground has already a testbench

Comment: BTW, you can thank me by marking this as a correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is improper nesting of `begin/end` blocks with the first `else`. Your indentation does not match what the compiler sees. And I'm sure you meant `==` instead of `+=`

Comment: += was a mistake. Thanks a lot